# S-video problems Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: video, xubuntu, resolution, radeon, tv

I installed for the first time Linux and it's a great move for me.
Xubuntu came out of the box with almost everything working perfectly.

I have a problem though, when I try to see the image from the screen onto the tv, the image is moving continuous and very fast to the left(on tv).

I tried different software to output the image in different resolutions. I tried to make for S-video output, custom resolutions and refresh rates in the terminal, but the image is still moving(in windows was ok, but don't wanna go back).

My laptop:Asus F3u,

```
graphic card *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=64
       resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fd6f0000-fd6fffff ioport:8800(size=256) memory:fd500000-fd5fffff
```

TV- Sony KE-32TS2E http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/KE-32TS2E/manuals

I can connect to TV only through S-video. Please help.

PS: if you know a good website with tutorials for using the terminal and Xubuntu in general, please share.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

sorry of being late. try to change the pal system to ntsc.

```
xrandr --output S-video --set "tv standard" ntsc
```